# AccessViolationException when accessing unmanaged C++ DLL with C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am trying to access a Double Dummy Solver dll (http://privat.bahnhof.se/wb758135/bridge/dll.html ) of unmanaged C++ code from a C# project, but I get the following error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Dds.Net.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The error seems to be around calling the method
Par which takes the three arguments

> struct ddTableResults *tablep,  struct parResults *presp,  int vulnerable

Specifically, related to passing in the 2nd parameter which is described to be:

> struct parResults 
>   char parScore[2][16]; 
>   char parContractsString [2][128];

Here is my code:
My c# struct:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Dds.Net.Integration
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct ParResults
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst =32)]
        public char[,] parScore;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
        public char[,] parContractString;


    }
}
```

dllimport to call the function :

```
[DllImport("dds.dll")]
        public static extern int Par(DdTableResults tablep, int vulnerable, ParResults parResults);
```

Any idea of what I can do to get this working?

Many thanks!

Comment: c# signature does not match with the c++ signature you gave us: `public static extern int Par(DdTableResults tablep, int vulnerable, ParResults parResults);` vs `struct ddTableResults *tablep, struct parResults *presp, int vulnerable` (2nd and 3rd param swapped)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've switched the parameters around now but it still results in the SystemViolation exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I understand, you c++ signature is

```
int Par(struct ddTableResults *tablep, struct parResults *presp, int vulnerable)
```

the c# one maybe is

```
[DllImport("dds.dll")]
public static extern int Par(ref DdTableResults tablep, ref ParResults parResults, int vulnerable);
```

c++ wants a poitner to `DdTableResults` and `ParResults`, without `ref` c# will pass structure by value.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the access violation which enabled me to debug the rest of my program quite quickly and get things running!