# AccessViolationException when accessing function with char * argument in c++ dll with C#

Tags: c#, c++

**Problem** Trying to use a function in a c++ dll with the following prototype...

```c
int connectDfuBootloader(char * usbIndex)
```

...from C#, using any of these P/Invoke signatures, causes an AccessViolationException:

1. IntPtr...

```c#
[DllImport(@"CubeProgrammer_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int connectDfuBootloader(IntPtr usbIndex);

public static int connectDfuBootloader(string usbIndex)
{            
    IntPtr value = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(usbIndex);
    return connectDfuBootloader(value);
}
```

2. String...

```c#
[DllImport(@"CubeProgrammer_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int connectDfuBootloader(string usbIndex);
```

3. StringBuilder...

```c#
[DllImport(@"CubeProgrammer_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int connectDfuBootloader(StringBuilder usbIndex);
```

4. Variations on the theme of MarshalAs, tried LPStr, LPTStr etc...

```c#
[DllImport(@"CubeProgrammer_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int connectDfuBootloader([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string usbIndex);
```

5. Variations on the theme of specifying the character set, ANSI, Unicode, etc

```c#
[DllImport(@"CubeProgrammer_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet =CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int connectDfuBootloader(string usbIndex);
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

**Other things I've tried**

Various StackOverflow posts, such as
[AccessViolationException when accessing unmanaged C++ DLL with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843311/accessviolationexception-when-accessing-unmanaged-c-dll-with-c-sharp)

Also, I tried making my own small C++ dll for test purposes, which contained a function with the same signature as the problem one above:

```c
int functionAlpha(char * a)
{   
    if (a[0] == 'a')
        return 10;
    else
        return 20;
}
```

This function I was able to access from C# without issue, using any of the methods above, e.g.

```c#
[DllImport(@"test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int functionAlpha(string a);
```

Which makes me think there is something special about the 'int connectDfuBootloader(char * usbIndex)' function. But they have the same signature, why would one work and the other not? I do not have the source code for the dll, so can't look in there to see if there are any other differences.

**Update - Tried C++/CLI wrapper as suggested by @Taekahn below, same thing!**

So, I have this in a header in the C++/CLI wrapper project:

```c++
#include "include/CubeProgrammer_API.h"

using namespace System;
namespace CLI
{
    public ref class CubeWrapper
    {
    public:        
        int wrappedConnectDfuBootloader(String^ a);
    };
}
```

Then in a cpp file in the wrapper project, I have:

```c++
namespace CLI
{
    static char* string_to_ncchar_array(String^ string)
    {
        char* str = (char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(string)).ToPointer();
        return str;
    }

    int CubeWrapper::wrappedConnectDfuBootloader(String^ a)
    {        
        a = "USB0";
        // Calls the function from the linked c++ dll I'm trying to wrap
        return connectDfuBootloader(string_to_ncchar_array(a));        
    }
}
```

And it gives the same result, System.AccessViolationException! What could be going on here?

**Also tried using the dll from c++**
Tried the same sequence of operations with the dll from a c++ application, and it worked fine.

Comment: My suggestion would be to abandon pinvoke and call the function from a C++/CLI wrapper. Its 1000 times easier than pinvoke.
That aside, is there more to the error message?

Comment: `CallingConvention.Cdecl` That should probably be `StdCall` instead.

Comment: @Taekahn There wasn't anything else useful in the exception message. I will try the C++/CLI wrapper approach you suggest.

Comment: @dxiv Tried StdCall, same result.

Comment: `But they have the same signature, why would one work and the other not?` - because they in fact don't have the same signature? Because the access violation actually happens inside the function?

Comment: @raml `I do not have the source code for the dll` Then your options are quite limited at this point. You may have guessed the signature wrong, or maybe that function relies on something else being called first, or any number of possible failure causes.

Comment: @GSerg I have the headers and documentation for the dll, and all agree on the function signature, plus, the same function and sequence of operations work correctly when used from c++

Comment: I see you got the same error using the wrapper.  
Not sure if it will make a difference, but i usually marshal my strings like this `marshal_as<std::string>(input).c_str()` Where input is a `String^`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that dxiv was on the right track; looked through some of the c++ example code supplied with the API and saw that several callbacks had to be setup first. Once I sorted those, problem fixed.

Comment: So glad you answered your own question. "setDisplayCallbacks" must be called first right ? Not sure I've find it out. PS: that API sucks ;D